# Query syntax is not valid near identifier 'PIVOT'

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to run a dynamic SQL query in Entity Framework 4

I'm created my query as a string, it becomes this:

```
SELECT 
    NodeID 
    ,RowID 
    ,[Comment]
    ,[Subject]
    ,[Text] 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        nr.Node_ID as NodeID 
        ,nr.ID as RowID 
        ,f.Name 
        ,d.Value 
    FROM NoteNode.dbo.[NodeRows] AS nr 
    LEFT JOIN NoteNode.dbo.[NodeData] AS d ON nr.ID = d.NodeRow_ID 
    LEFT JOIN NoteNode.dbo.[NodeFields] AS f ON f.ID = d.Field_ID 
    WHERE nr.Node_ID = (1) ) AS x 
    PIVOT 
    ( 
        MAX(Value) 
        for Name IN ([Comment],[Subject],[Text]) 
    ) AS p
```

Running this code straight in MSSQL Studio works perfectly, no problems at all.. 
However, when I try to run this using entity framework using this:

```
var DataRecords = new ObjectQuery<DbDataRecord>(dataQuery, (ObjectContext) _db.ObjectContext());
```

It does not work, and gives me the following error:

> {"The query syntax is not valid. Near identifier 'PIVOT', line 17, column 31."}

Tried to mess around with the syntax a bit and also to clear out all newlines and tabs but I keep coming back to this error.

Any ideas?

FYI: I'm open to suggestions for how this could be converted to LINQ/LAMBDA or if I should be doing this in an entierly different manner.

Comment: [`ObjectQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb345303.aspx): "The query itself can be created by using an Entity SQL statement or a LINQ query" - you've provided T-SQL - neither of those options.

Comment: Post on MSDN suggest you can use T-SQL and claims it is working. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/adodotnetentityframework/thread/48019c0c-285a-4b4f-b3cc-32985921eaea

Comment: Using T-SQL with ObjectQuery in a post here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918071/return-custom-object-list-t-from-entity-framework-and-assign-to-object-data-so

Comment: That looks like fairly standard SQL in those questions - it's neither identified as T-SQL not Entity SQL. But you're trying to use something that's quite strongly part of the T-SQL dialect.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever hmm, yeah your right about that. Any suggestion as to how I should be doing this?

Comment: Just a quick idea, would you not be able to create a view in you DB with that T-SQL and then import that view into your EF model? that way you would know that EF would not reject it.

Comment: @Qpirate that is a possability, the problem is that its not my database and that it can change alot at any given time. For that option to really work I would have to figure out some way to programatically add the function if it is missing from my code.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `ObjectQuery` for executing raw SQL. Use `ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery` instead.

Comment: Any examples of how to do this? I havent found any good ones yet.

Comment: Create class with properties named as columns in your query result set and execute `objectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<YourClass>(dataQuery)`

Comment: Just running  `var DataRecords3 = _db.ObjectContext().ExecuteStoreQuery<DbDataRecord>(dataQuery);` Results in this error: 
**The result type 'System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord' may not be abstract and must include a default constructor.** I'm guessing this means I can't use `<DbDataRecord>` and must instead define a type with specific columns.. which is not something I can do (I never know how many columns the query will end up returning as it is generated at runtime).

Comment: You cannot query for data record but for strongly typed class. If you don't know how many columns do you have in result set EF is not tool for you. Use `SqlDataReader` instead.

Comment: For everything else besides this query I know what columns I'll be getting back (using LINQ for those queries). Was hoping I diden't have to resort to opening a separate connection for this but seems thats the only way =/